# Gigabytes of GetRecording.dat and GetVideo.dat files...what are they?

Tags: windows-7

I've just located several gigabytes of GetRecording[a number].dat and GetVideo.dat files in the Windows/Temporary Internet Files/Content.IE5 directory.

Any idea what these are?

Comment: Is this just for curiosity? These are, after all, temporary Internet files.

Comment: Well, the main thing is that neither disk cleanup nor emptying my browser caches seems to delete them. They all seem to be in the last few months. I don't use IE and clearing the Firefox cache doesn't clear them either. Also odd that I can't seem to find anything on Google.

Comment: YouTube videos are all named getvideo(1), getvideo(2), etc...delete if you don't want them.

Comment: @ahmed - put your comment as an answer

Comment: I thought that might be, based on their size, but why wouldn't they disappear when I clear my caches?

Comment: Content.IE5 is not considered cache and is never cleared. You have to do it manually and is safe to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Firefox and you have the Adobe Flash Player plugin installed and you watch videos on YouTube using Flash rather than HTML5, Flash Player will use the following location to cache data:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\
```

Comment: Thanks. Looked at the flash player's global settings and can't seem to locate a cache size setting. So is it always a manual clearing task?